# Displaying BLOB Images in PDF Reports - Oracle APEX

Tags: pdf, printing, oracle11g, blob, oracle-apex

I've been trying to output BLOBs in my PDF reports using Oracle BI Publisher as my printing server. I have
no issues with really small images but when the image size increases I get no output. I'm using the method
proposed in this blog post :
https://blogs.oracle.com/xmlpublisher/entry/inserting_blobs_into_your_repo

I noticed Scott Wesley had also faced the same issue.
This is the table I'm using to keep my images stored in :

```
CREATE TABLE MY_IMAGES (
  ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  IMAGE BLOB,
  FILE_NAME VARCHAR2(50),
  MIME_TYPE VARCHAR2(30)
);
/
```

I'm using Tim Hall's function to encode the BLOB column to Base64 :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION base64encode(p_blob IN BLOB)
RETURN CLOB
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- File Name : http://oracle-base.com/dba/miscellaneous/base64encode.sql
- Author : Tim Hall
- Description : Encodes a BLOB into a Base64 CLOB.
- Last Modified: 09/11/2011
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IS
l_clob CLOB;
l_step PLS_INTEGER := 12000; - make sure you set a multiple of 3 not higher than 24573
BEGIN
FOR i IN 0 .. TRUNC((DBMS_LOB.getlength(p_blob) - 1 )/l_step) LOOP
l_clob := l_clob || UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode
(DBMS_LOB.substr(p_blob,
l_step, i * l_step + 1)));
END LOOP;
RETURN l_clob;
END;
```

This is my select statement as my Report Query :

```
SELECT FILE_NAME, BASE64ENCODE(IMAGE)
FROM MY_IMAGES
```

And in my RTF Report Layout I'm using this code to render the encoded BLOB :

```
<fo:instream-foreign-object content-type="image/jpg">
<xsl:value-of select="IMAGE"/>
</fo:instream-foreign-object>
```

I inserted a 5KB image in the table and it's working perfectly, but when I tried with a 500Kb image, there was
no result.
I was wondering whether anyone had come up with a solution, or if this issue was solved. I'm on APEX 5.1 on
an 11g Database and using BI Publisher 11g.
I appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: have you created a demo on OAC if yes i will look into it.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken the OAC doesn't have print server settings in its instance settings. And I tested on OAC a couple of days ago, lots of the basic functionality didn't work correctly. Anyhow, I found the solution which I will post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding displaying BLOB images in PDF reports, the limit is 32KB

Here is a nice workaround :

[Marc Sewtz: Dynamic Images in PDF - What 32k Limit?](http://marcsewtz.blogspot.com/2012/02/dynamic-images-in-pdf-what-32k-limit.html)